# Win32 Keyboard Accelerator Not Working C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, handle

I've been trying to make a keyboard shortcut in my Win32 application. It is an F5 refresh shortcut.

I've been following this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646337%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#wm_command.

I've included this in a "menu.rc" file:

```
IDR_MYACC ACCELERATORS
BEGIN
    VK_F5, ID_EDIT_REFRESH, VIRTKEY
END
```

And this in the "main.cpp" file:

```
HWND   hwnd;
HANDLE hinstAcc;
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("CPUTemp");
    MSG        msg;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    BOOL       bRet;

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYICON));
    wc.hIconSm       = (HICON)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYICON), 
                                        IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, 0);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1); // use default colour as window background
    wc.lpszMenuName  = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MYMENU);
    wc.lpszClassName = szAppName;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, szAppName, "CPU Temperature", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 150, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), 0);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    HACCEL haccel = LoadAccelerators(hinstAcc, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MYACC));

    if (haccel == NULL) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Accelerator Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // get and dispatch messages until a WM_QUIT message is received
    while ((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0)
    {
        if (bRet == -1) {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Message Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
            return 0;
        } else {
            // Check for accelerator keystrokes
            if (!TranslateAccelerator( 
                hwnd,   // handle to receiving window 
                haccel, // handle to active accelerator table 
                &msg))  // message data 
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg); // translate virtual-key messages into character messages
                DispatchMessage(&msg);  // send message to window procedure 
            }
        }
    }

    return msg.wParam; // the program return-value is 0 - value that PostQuitMessage() gave
}
```

The problem occurs when compiling - I get an error saying "invalid conversion from 'HANDLE aka void' to 'HINSTANCE' for this line:

```
HACCEL haccel = LoadAccelerators(hinstAcc, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MYACC));
```

But if I try replacing "hinstAcc" with "hInstance", it compiles and runs, but the accelerator ends up being NULL.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

re the compilation problem:

use `hInstance`, or better, use `GetModuleHandle(0)` and ditch the silly, verbose and non-standard `WinMain` (use standard `main` instead)

more generally, just consult the **documentation** about Windows API function arguments

e.g. google `LoadAccelerators`, click on the link to MSDN docs.

---

re

> “ if I try replacing "hinstAcc" with "hInstance", it compiles and runs, but the accelerator ends up being NULL.”

I can't see any reason in the provided code.

Maybe you've forgot to link in the resources.

Comment: how would I do it via int main() ?

Comment: you just use `int main()` instead of `int WinMain( blah blah )`. with microsoft's tools, also add `/entry:mainCRTStartup` to linker options.

Comment: It's ok, I've been using MinGW and I didn't realise I did have to link the resource file using windres.